# Even spacing for exercise sheet

Tags: exercises

I want to create a design for an exercise sheet. That's what I've got so far:

```
\documentclass[DIV=15]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\points}[1]{{\small\textbf{(#1)}}}

\newcounter{ExCount}

\newenvironment{exercise}
[2]
{\refstepcounter{ExCount}\par\medskip\noindent\textbf{Exercise \arabic{ExCount}%
        \ifstrempty{#1}{}{~\normalfont(#1)}} \hfill{\small (Points: \textbf{#2})}%
    \hrule\vspace{\itemsep}\noindent\newline}
{\par\medskip}

\newlist{exlist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[exlist,1]{label=\roman*)}
\setlist[exlist,2]{label=\alph*)}

\newcommand*\raiseup[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \setbox0\hbox{\tiny\strut #1}%
    \leavevmode
    \raise\dimexpr \ht\strutbox - \ht0\box0
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        Some Course (2019) \hfill
        Prof. xyz $\cdot$ xyz
        \hrule

        \vspace{0.2cm}
        {\large \textbf{Exercise 01} } \hfill \raiseup{\small Total points: \textbf{4 points + 4 extra points*}}

        \vspace{0.1cm}
        \small\raggedright (Deadline: 20/04/2019)
    \end{center}

    %%%%%
    %
    % Some Topic
    %
    %%%%%
    \begin{exercise}{Some Topic}{10}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{exercise}

    %%%%%
    %
    % Some Other Topic
    %
    %%%%%
    \begin{exercise}{Some Other Topic}{8}
        \begin{exlist}
            \item This is some exercise about weird math stuff.
            \item This is another exercise about more weird math stuff.
            \begin{exlist}
                \item This is some exercise about weird math stuff.
                \item This is another exercise about more weird math stuff.
            \end{exlist}
        \end{exlist}
    \end{exercise}

    %%%%%
    %
    % More Topics
    %
    %%%%%
    \begin{exercise}{More Topics}{8}
        Let something be something. Then:
        \begin{exlist}
            \item This is some exercise about weird math stuff.
            \item This is another exercise about more weird math stuff.
            \begin{exlist}
                \item This is some exercise about weird math stuff.
                \item This is another exercise about more weird math stuff.
            \end{exlist}
        \end{exlist}
    \end{exercise}

    \hrule
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \centering
    Good luck! :)
\end{document}
```

But now, the lists cause undesireable spacings. I want that spacing is everywhere the same (especially before and after the lists, like there is none). Do you know, how to manage that?

And, moreover, do you have any suggestions for improvements?

[image: This is how it looks like.]

Comment: Did you try with the `nosep` option, since you load `enumitem`?

Comment: Compiling your code produces errors.

Comment: Yes, the very first line is still clean. At best, I don't want to have a dirty solution. Sorry. Corrected. I naively changed a bit manually.

Comment: `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.60     \end{exercise}`

Comment: You have still the issue? It works fine for me now. :-/

Comment: Off-Topic: Removing the csquotes-package strangely causes an error. Does anybody has an idea why so? :D

Comment: No I don't have the issue any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this more like you want?

```
\documentclass[DIV=15]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\points}[1]{{\small\textbf{(#1)}}}

\newcounter{ExCount}

\newenvironment{exercise}
[2]
{\refstepcounter{ExCount}\par\medskip\noindent\textbf{Exercise \arabic{ExCount}%
        \ifstrempty{#1}{}{~\normalfont(#1)}} \hfill{\small (Points: \textbf{#2})}%
    \hrule\vspace{\itemsep}\noindent\newline}
{\par\medskip}

\newlist{exlist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[exlist,1]{label=\roman*)}
\setlist[exlist,2]{label=\alph*)}

\newcommand*\raiseup[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \setbox0\hbox{\tiny\strut #1}%
    \leavevmode
    \raise\dimexpr \ht\strutbox - \ht0\box0
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        Some Course (2019) \hfill
        Prof. xyz $\cdot$ xyz
        \hrule

        \vspace{0.2cm}
        {\large \textbf{Exercise 01} } \hfill \raiseup{\small Total points: \textbf{4 points + 4 extra points*}}

        \vspace{0.1cm}
        \small\raggedright (Deadline: 20/04/2019)
    \end{center}

    %%%%%
    %
    % Some Topic
    %
    %%%%%
    \begin{exercise}{Some Topic}{10}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{exercise}

    %%%%%
    %
    % Some Other Topic
    %
    %%%%%
    \begin{exercise}{Some Other Topic}{8}
        \begin{exlist}[topsep = 0pt, before= \vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip }]
            \item This is some exercise about weird math stuff.
            \item This is another exercise about more weird math stuff.
            \begin{exlist}
                \item This is some exercise about weird math stuff.
                \item This is another exercise about more weird math stuff.
            \end{exlist}
        \end{exlist}
    \end{exercise}

    %%%%%
    %
    % More Topics
    %
    %%%%%
    \begin{exercise}{More Topics}{8}
        Let something be something. Then:
        \begin{exlist}
            \item This is some exercise about weird math stuff.
            \item This is another exercise about more weird math stuff.
            \begin{exlist}
                \item This is some exercise about weird math stuff.
                \item This is another exercise about more weird math stuff.
            \end{exlist}
        \end{exlist}
    \end{exercise}

    \hrule
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \centering
    Good luck! :)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! How did you determine the \baselineskip as appropriate distance?

Comment: Well, what's added at the beginning and at the end of a list is 1\baselineskip + 1\topsepèing set `\topsep` to 0, it was not hard to guess what had to be removed.